# Loading speedbar on emacs startup

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I use emacs 23.3.1 on ubuntu 12.04. I installed speedbar on it. The emacs init file looks like this :

```
 ;;; Emacs Load Path
 (setq load-path (cons "~/emacs-config" load-path))

 ;; speedbar in the same frame
 (require 'sr-speedbar)
 (load "~/emacs-config/sr-speedbar")
```

emacs-config has sr-speedbar.el. I don't get any error message on load. However, speedbar is not started on loading. I have to M-x sr-speedbar-open every time I start emacs.

Also, is there a way to start sr-speedbar in buffers mode always. Right now it is in files mode so it shows the listing of the directory of the current file.

Comment: Perhaps you can help me better understand a few things so that I might be able to help you in return.  According to the information that gets listed when I type `C-h m` on the speedbar buffer, *Speedbar mode defined in 'speedbar.el': Major mode for managing a display of directories and tags.*.  Unless I'm mistaken, the buffer is a separate animal that runs independently of other buffers when other major modes are present.  Is your question, "How can I enable a separate speedbar buffer on startup?"  If so, then perhaps something simple like `(speedbar)` in your `.emacs` file after `(require..)`

Comment: For finer control over when functions load on startup, there are three hooks normally used -- `before-init-hook`, `after-init-hook`, and `emacs-startup-hook`.  I personally like the `emacs-startup-hook` -- e.g., `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (function-one) (function-two) (setq ...) (message "hello-world") ))`

Comment: Thanks lawlist. My question is "How do I enable speedbar buffer BUT in the same emacs windows". when I add (speedbar) to .emacs I get two different windows one for speedbar and another for emacs. Your second response though made things much clearer. Instead of (speedbar), I do (sr-speedbar-open) and that makes the speedbar show in the same window. If you can respond by saying that add   (sr-speedbar-open) into the .emacs, then I can accept it as a correct answer. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to add `(sr-speedbar-open)` into the `.emacs` file, underneath the line of code `(load "~/emacs-config/sr-speedbar")`.

A second method would be to use either the `after-init-hook` or the `emacs-startup-hook` -- that would permit the entire `.emacs` file to be loaded before anything inside the hook is executed.  Additional functions or settings can be added to the hook using the following method:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
  (sr-speedbar-open)
  ))
```